# Settings button are not available with listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Where is setting button (3 small points in right corner) ? And how to return it?
When I started to use ListView with another layout , my action bar dissapear.
May be reason is using another layout?
[image]

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] values = new String[100];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    for (int i=0;i<=99;i++){
        values[i]=Integer.toString(i+1);

    }
    MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: You hide (or just use the theme without) actionbar.

Comment: Do you mean where is the Action Bar and overflow menu?

Comment: @PPartisan Yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

To use the default `ActionBar`:

Ensure your app's theme (in `styles.xml` has a `Theme.AppCompat.*` parent which also contains an `ActionBar`. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/specify_action_bar_color_here</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/specify_status_bar_color_here</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/specify_widget_color_here</item>
</style>
```

Then, ensure your `Activity` class extends `AppCompatActivity`, rather than simply `Activity`. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //...
}
```